# Swap HDD in bcache

Tags: linux

I have a bcache setup involving an SSD and HDD.  The HDD is starting to fail and I have a replacement on order.  What is the best approach for exchanging the HDD?

---

I have a thought that I could:

1. Temporarily stop bcache
2. Use a tool like ddrescue to copy the content of the HDD to the replacement
3. Remove the old drive, and start bcache again.

If I use ddrescue to copy the entire drive, then the replacement drive will have partitions with exactly the same UUIDs as before, and bcache ought to be none-the-wiser.

It looks like I can stop bcache by writing `1` to a `stop` file in `/sys` somewhere, but it's not obvious to me which file exactly as there are at least two in the bcache docs: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/bcache.txt

Any thoughts on the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. If you have lvm, then a possible solution would be pvmove. Please keep in mind that this would be risky, because if pvmove gets interrupted/crashes you'll have corrupted data ( first tip would be to run the pvmove in a screen ).

If you don't use lvm, I guess a way would be to use sfdisk to clone the partition table and then dd/rsync the data.